# Can a non dual-channel motherboard be paired with dual-channel RAM, or the other way around?

Tags: memory, motherboard, dual-channel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dual Channel RAM vs. Quad Channel RAM](https://superuser.com/questions/87175/dual-channel-ram-vs-quad-channel-ram)

What is the criteria for motherboard ↔ RAM compatibility with regards to multi-channel capabilities?

Can a non dual-channel motherboard be paired with dual-channel RAM, or the other way around?

Comment: Also see: [Should I be worrying about Single Channel and Double Channel for my RAM?](http://superuser.com/questions/9666/should-i-be-worrying-about-single-channel-and-double-channel-for-my-ram)

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing as Dual Channel RAM. :)

(Dual Channel) Kits of RAM are just multiple identical sticks sold together by a manufacturer, to ensure the best compatibility.

Comment: oh, ok. good to know :)